# RCC SMPS circuit modify

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: Generic RCC smps circuit]

Its a classic ringing choke converter smps circuit found in chargers. This one yields 240ma @9v, need to modify to get 2A@5v, already have a 5v2A flyback dc dc transformer.

Just need the changed component values, market is full of ready made chargers of same, but want to make it on my own.

Comment: What is your question? Ask a specific question so it can be answered

Comment: How the others are answering?

Answer (score 1):

Your voltage is set by ZD1, an 8.2 volt zener plus the Vbe drop of T1. To drop it down to 5 volts ZD1 needs to be a 4.3 volt zener diode, 500 mW.

*I should warn you* that this trick may work fine, but the transformer has a specific turns ratio for a given output voltage. Changing ZD1 by such a large amount could take the circuit out of its tracking range, causing it to stop or T1 shorts out or it works but not with a 2 amp load.

Comment: Thanks, real help, yes, I guessed the o/p here i.e. 9v and  relation between zener value. In another forum, I was told to try with R1 and R2, though without specific values.

Comment: I already have a salvaged 5v/2a flyback transformer, very clearly rated, quite unusual for such little ccomponent, maybe because of the large current  it supposed to deal with.

Comment: In some similar smps circuits with some modified means, another transistor normally c945 is added, but in that case, o/p current is much lower, few miliamps.

Comment: The zener diode helps regulate the voltage, but this voltage is within the range of the transformer. I have made many transformers to get what I want, usually 1,500 volts or 15 volts at 20 amps. The windings of the transformer put a severe limit on what it can do which is why adjustable power supplies often use a conventional transformer and linear regulators.